# The value must be of type 'xx' error by restricted access

Tags: typo3, extbase

I have a product database extension. Based on **Extbase + Fluid**. 
Everything working like it should be, but I have a Problem with restricted Access.

There are some products only for a certain group of users. When I set a group, and somebody uses a direkt link to this product, the login site should come in case of no login.

It is working for sites, but with products I get the:

**"The value must be of type "xx", but was of type "NULL". "** error

I also using realUrl.

the `enable404forInvalidAlias` is set for my extension, so a non-existing product call leads to the 404 page, but unfortunetly I couldn't handle till now the restricted access question.

Version is: **4.5.22**
Solution should be work without major update.

UPDATE:

In my `showAction` the product defined with `= NULL` default value.

I have already a condition in my fluid template like this:

```
<f:if condition="{product}">
...
</f:if>
```

The error message coming from this line:

```
Tx_Extbase_MVC_Exception_InvalidArgumentValue thrown in file
\typo3\sysext\extbase\Classes\MVC\Controller\Argument.php 
in line 389.
```

I made some debug and the whole showAction runs through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the action in a way so that it allows for no-instances of your product and check for the existance within fluid:

```
public function showAction(Tx_YourExt_Domain_Model_Product $product = NULL) ..
```

in Fluid:

```
<f:if condition="{product}">
   <f:then> <!-- show your product --> </f:then>
   <f:else> 
      <!-- show a login form, e.g. something you have in typoscript -->
   </f:else>
</f:if>
```

Downside of this is, that you can't handle proper 404's easily.

There's an [ifAuthenticated viewhelper](https://fedext.net/viewhelpers/fluid/Security/IfAuthenticatedViewHelper.html) as well and in combination with the above it should be straight forward to handle proper 404's as well. I'm not sure which TYPO3 version this has been introduced though.

Comment: Actually both of them are good suggestion, but I have them also. To the error I update my question, I think the problem is in that part, when it tries to load the object, but because of the restricted (fe_group) acces it can't be returned, and here comes this exception from the core.

Comment: I reviewed my code, there was a missing = NULL declaration. Thanks for the help, that was leading me to the solution.